# Multiple divs are being added to form when using jquery modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel, modal-dialog

I have jquery modal window. I open this window  clicking on the **click here** ref, here is my code:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" ID="Button" />
        <a onclick ="$('#divReuse').dialog();" href="#">click here</a>
        <div id="divReuse">
            this is content of the modal window.
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have a button in my update panel. When I click the button it does a postback (asyncronously).After this postback inside update panel, again I click on the link **click here** 
[image]

**The problem** is that jquery adds extra divs with the same content to my markup
[image]

Comment: create demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem. Not enough code shown

Comment: Unable to create a similar demo, because I have an asp.net code involved.

Comment: code you use on server is completely irrelevant... it outputs html and that html can be easily obtained from browser , ether in `view source` or from a browser console. The browser and the script run in browser have no connection whatsoever to asp.net

Comment: thing is that with every postback inside updatepanel $('#divReuse').dialog(); function adds new div. Very upset about this. Now I have to use another plugin.

Comment: nobody can help if you don't show code that creates these elements.... can also be removed when dialog is closed. Problem is within your code, not dialog plugin

Comment: I wrote all code that I have.

Comment: no...you provided server code...where's the client side source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I delete jquery generated div when close button is pushed. like this:

```
 $('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all').remove();
```